# Which pair of functions satisfy f (N) ~g(N)?

Tags: math, asymptotic-complexity

I've just started working with algorithms and I am doing some tasks like this question:

I think, the right answer is A. As the functions are the same, or do I miss something?

Question:

[image]

Comment: E. Another pair of functions which satisfies `h(N) ~ i(N)`.

Comment: What? That's not a possible answer in the question I posted?

Comment: What's this tilde defined as, and are you only supposed to pick one answer? It looks to me like there are multiple correct choices.

Comment: Only 1 answer is allowed.

Comment: A ... need more characters :)

Comment: @user2357112 The tilde relation here means "the limit of f / g, as n tends toward infinity, is 1." See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) for details.

Comment: I think if f ~ g, then f = O(g) according to Meyer et.al.'s "Math for CS".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [cs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is A. Notice that in that case,

> f(N) = N + 2N + 3N = 6N = g(N)

so f(N) ~ g(N).

For the functions given in B, notice that

> f(N) = (N + 1) + (N + 2) + (N + 3) = 3N + 6

so the limit of f(N) / g(N) as N tends toward infinity is 3, and therefore f(N) is not tilde of g(N).

For the functions in C, notice that

> f(N) / g(N) = 1 / N<sup>5</sup> + 1 / N<sup>4</sup> + 1 / N<sup>3</sup>

and, in the limit, this does not tend to one.

For the functions in D, notice that

> f(N) = log N + log 2N + log 3N = log 6N<sup>3</sup> = 3 log 6N

so the limit of f(N) over g(N) as N tends toward infinity is 3, so the functions aren't tilde of one another.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: `<sup>` tags. You can see the answer's source code in the edit view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, A is the correct answer.

Tilde here means an (approximate, not precise) equivalence relation. Or in other words, the limit of f(N) / g(N) as N approaches infinity = 1.

In answer A, f and g are obviously equivalent, so the limit is 1. This doesn't hold for the other three answers, which have limits 3, 0, and 3 respectively.